# Loading days of the month only works for the first month selected but not for the rest Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, calendar

I'm building a date select box, everything loads simply fine when I click for the first time on any month, it updates the calendar, but when I click on another month nothing happens...
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
  <form action="" method="get">
    <div id="date_select">
    <div id="mess_btns">
    <input type="radio" name="mes" value="" style="display: none;" required>
    <div class="mes_cont">
      <input type="radio" name="mes" id="mes1" value="1">
      <label for="mes1">Ene</label>
    </div>
    <div class="mes_cont">
      <input type="radio" name="mes" id="mes2" value="2">
      <label for="mes2">Feb</label>
    </div>
    <div class="mes_cont">
      <input type="radio" name="mes" id="mes3" value="3">
      <label for="mes3">Mar</label>
    </div>
    <div class="mes_cont">
      <input type="radio" name="mes" id="mes4" value="4">
      <label for="mes4">Abr</label>
    </div>
    <div class="mes_cont">
      <input type="radio" name="mes" id="mes5" value="5">
      <label for="mes5">May</label>
    </div>
    <div class="mes_cont">
      <input type="radio" name="mes" id="mes6" value="6">
      <label for="mes6">Jun</label>
    </div>
    <div class="mes_cont">
      <input type="radio" name="mes" id="mes7" value="7">
      <label for="mes7">Jul</label>
    </div>
    <div class="mes_cont">
      <input type="radio" name="mes" id="mes8" value="8">
      <label for="mes8">Ago</label>
    </div>
    <div class="mes_cont">
      <input type="radio" name="mes" id="mes9" value="9">
      <label for="mes9">Sep</label>
    </div>
    <div class="mes_cont">
      <input type="radio" name="mes" id="mes10" value="10">
      <label for="mes10">Oct</label>
    </div>
    <div class="mes_cont">
      <input type="radio" name="mes" id="mes11" value="11">
      <label for="mes11">Nov</label>
    </div>
    <div class="mes_cont">
      <input type="radio" name="mes" id="mes12" value="12">
      <label for="mes12">Dic</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="dias_btns">
  </div>
  <div id="anyos_cont">
    <select class="year_select" name="ano" id="ano">
    </select>
  </div>
 </div>
 <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
 </form>
 <script>
  var meses = document.getElementsByName("mes");
  for (var i = 0; i < meses.length; i++) {
  meses[i].onclick = function() {
    valor = this.value;
    console.log(valor);
    };
  }
var year = new Date().getFullYear();
var select = document.getElementById("ano");
for (var i = year - 16; i > year - 56; i--) {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = i;
  option.text = i;
  select.appendChild(option);
}
var select = document.getElementById("ano");
select.style.width = "200px";
select.style.height = "40px";
select.style.fontSize = "1.5rem";
select.style.textAlign = "center";
select.style.textAlignLast = "center";


var dias_cont = document.getElementById("dias_btns");
var dias = 31;
var mes = 0;
var dia = 0;
var mes = document.getElementsByName("mes");

function dias_mes() {
  for (var i = 0; i < mes.length; i++) {
    if (mes[i].checked) {
      mes = mes[i].value;
    }
  }
  if (mes == 1 || mes == 3 || mes == 5 || mes == 7 || mes == 8 || mes == 10 || mes == 12) {
    dias = 31;
  } else if (mes == 4 || mes == 6 || mes == 9 || mes == 11) {
    dias = 30;
  } else if (mes == 2) {
    dias = 28;
  }
  dias_cont.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 1; i <= dias; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "dias_cont";
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "radio";
    input.name = "dia";
    input.id = "dia" + i;
    input.value = i;
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    label.htmlFor = "dia" + i;
    label.innerHTML = i;
    div.appendChild(input);
    div.appendChild(label);
    dias_cont.appendChild(div);
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < mes.length; i++) {
  mes[i].onclick = function() {
    dias_mes();
  };
 }
 dias_mes();

</script>

<style>
    #mess_btns {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: flex;
        gap: 2px;
        width: 260px;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .mes_cont label {
        width: 78px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #fdfdfd;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        border-radius: 6px;
        border: 1px solid #e2e4ea;
        color: #818181;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: background-color 200ms ease;
    }

    .mes_cont {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .mes_cont>input[type="radio"] {
        display: none;
    }

    .mes_cont input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
        background-color: #ffaf00;
        color: #fff;
        text-shadow: -1px 1px 0 #c47b1a;
        border: 3px solid #ff9800;
    }

    #dias_btns {
        position: relative;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: flex;
        gap: 0.09rem;
        width: 260px;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        padding: 10px;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
    }

    .dias_cont label {
        width: 33px;
        height: 32px;
        background-color: #fdfdfd;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        border-radius: 6px;
        border: 1px solid #e2e4ea;
        color: #818181;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: background-color 200ms ease;
    }

    .dias_cont {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .dias_cont>input[type="radio"] {
        display: none;
    }

    .dias_cont input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
        background-color: #ffaf00;
        color: #fff;
        text-shadow: -1px 1px 0 #c47b1a;
        border: 3px solid #ff9800;
    }

    input[type="checkbox"].optin_chkbx {
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        transform: translate(16px, 7px);
        accent-color: #5693a1;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #e4e4e4 inset, 0 0 0 1px #e4e4e4;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }

    input[type="checkbox"].optin_chkbx:checked {
        background-color: #1e448c;
        color: #fff;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Your example is incomplete, could you include the HTML and CSS as well?

Comment: There, sorry for the omission :-)

Comment: I'm checking on the chrome inspector to see what's going on with the code and every time I clic a month I can see that the code updates, but not with the correct number of days.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still not able to reproduce the issue. Could you provide a minimal example?

Comment: Here's a working example https://jsfiddle.net/samramsan/69rkypg2/1/
if you clic on February first, you'll see it changes to 28 days, after that nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the `mes` variable only gets declared once therefore it only works once because the checked valued from the radio "cached" in that variable. I suggest that you instead just pass the selected month from the event object, so you won't need to run the loop for getting which radio button is checked, here is a working example with some additional comments:

```js
var meses = document.getElementsByName('mes');
for (var i = 0; i < meses.length; i++) {
  meses[i].onclick = function () {
    valor = this.value;
    console.log(valor);
  };
}
var year = new Date().getFullYear();
var select = document.getElementById('ano');
for (var i = year - 16; i > year - 56; i--) {
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.value = i;
  option.text = i;
  select.appendChild(option);
}
var select = document.getElementById('ano');
select.style.width = '200px';
select.style.height = '40px';
select.style.fontSize = '1.5rem';
select.style.textAlign = 'center';
select.style.textAlignLast = 'center';

var dias_cont = document.getElementById('dias_btns');
var dias = 31;
var dia = 0;
var mes = document.getElementsByName('mes');

function dias_mes(currentMonth) {
  // We no longer need to run the loop here in order to get the month 
  // value, as we already have the current month value passing down 
  // from the caller. And since the click event is fired whenever the 
  // month radio button is checked, this value gets updated correctly
  if (
    currentMonth == 1 ||
    currentMonth == 3 ||
    currentMonth == 5 ||
    currentMonth == 7 ||
    currentMonth == 8 ||
    currentMonth == 10 ||
    currentMonth == 12
  ) {
    dias = 31;
  } else if (
    currentMonth == 4 ||
    currentMonth == 6 ||
    currentMonth == 9 ||
    currentMonth == 11
  ) {
    dias = 30;
  } else if (currentMonth == 2) {
    dias = 28;
  }
  dias_cont.innerHTML = '';
  for (var i = 1; i <= dias; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'dias_cont';
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'radio';
    input.name = 'dia';
    input.id = 'dia' + i;
    input.value = i;
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.htmlFor = 'dia' + i;
    label.innerHTML = i;
    div.appendChild(input);
    div.appendChild(label);
    dias_cont.appendChild(div);
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < mes.length; i++) {
  mes[i].onclick = function (event) {
    // Here we obtain the month value from the event object
    const currentMonth = event.target.value;
    dias_mes(currentMonth);
  };
}
dias_mes();
```

Comment: I see... Thank You so much for your explanation, I'll dive deep to fully grasp the concept. It's working now! You genius konekoya.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know why my comment was deleted multiple times. But could you consider accepting the answer if this does help you?